# Стоит ли использовать функциональный компонент?

Tags: vue.js

В своем проекте, я много где использую библиотеку momentJs, для того чтобы я мог использовать функционал этой библиотеки в темплейте компонентов, мне нужно описывать в methods функцию и уже эту описанную функцию вставлять в template, мне бы не хотелось в каждом компоненте проекта описывать одну и ту же функции. Как я понял, я могу просто создать новый компонент и передавать в него дату и тогда достаточно будет вызывать этот компонент в компонентах где должна использоваться библиотека mometJs, но также я могу использовать функциональный компонент и мой вопрос как раз заключается в том, как лучше сделать, просто создать новый компонент в котором как раз будет описана функция в methods и вызывать его в нужных компонентах или же использовать render функцию?

Comment: Функциональный компонент от нефункционального отличается только синтаксисом описания (то есть: либо ты понял что-то неправильно, либо сформулировал задачу неточно). А для использования moment.js в Vue - есть библиотека **vue-moment**. В любом случае, этот вопрос следует закрыть как предполагающий мнения в качестве ответов.

Comment: В задаче сказано, что я хотел избавиться от рутиной работы по написанию методов в каждом компоненте где используется momentJs, ответ на этот вопрос это использование примесей(mixins)

Comment: Использование миксинов может закрывать какую-то индивидуальную потребность, но оно уж точно не является ответом на тот вопрос который тут был задан.

Comment: я не хочу писать в каждом компоненте methods:{ getDate(date){ return moment(date).format('L')} вместо этого я один раз напишу эту функцию в миксине и не буду тратить время на рутиные действия. Что значит индивидуальную потребность, можно поподробнее?

Comment: Это значит что "хочу"/"не хочу" являются личными переживаниями отдельно взятых людей. При этом, stackoverflow это тематический сайт о программировании: он посвящен не личным переживаниям, а созданию общей базы знаний - где задаются технические вопросы о конкретных задачах программирования, и на них даются конкретные технические ответы. Поэтому: если этот вопрос был написан неправильно (не о том) - то надо не объяснять свои желания в комментариях, а исправить вопрос.

Comment: Относительно миксинов - начиная с Vue 3, вместо них предпочтительнее использовать новый Composition API. Если работаешь с актуальной версией библиотеки, то советую изучить эту новую апишку: используя ее, можно решать те же задачи которые решаются миксинами, но без их недостатков.

Comment: Ну и, при использовании рекомендованной в первом комменте библиотеки **vue-moment** - вместо `getDate(date){ return moment(date).format('L')` (неважно где, в каждом компоненте или в примеси) в шаблонах можно писать просто `{{ date | moment('L') }}`. В терминах Vue, это называется фильтром.